# Отображение картинки в RecyclerView из БД виде ссылки

Tags: java, android, база-данных, изображения, recyclerview.adapter

В `RecyclerView` есть `ImageView` в который мне нужно отобразить картинку взятую из БД на сервере. Картинка на сервере находиться виде ссылки. Вся проблема в том что я не знаю как написать код для вытягивания картинки из БД, то есть чтобы вытянуть текст я создал класс в котором указал, где взять текст (ссылка из `Fragmet` с помощью `get`) и как его можно указать(указываю его в `Adapter`  для `RecyclerView`с помощью `set`).

Пример класса

```
public class R_POffer {

String mPackage_offer_title;

 public String get_Package_offer_title() {return mPackage_offer_title;}
 public void set_Package_offer_title(String TempTitle) {this.mPackage_offer_title = TempTitle;}
}
```

Пример как я вытягиваю текст в `Fragment`

```
String URL_POffer = "http://adawd/dbpo.php";
String GET_PO_TITLE = "title_po";

jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(URL_POffer, this::PARSE_R_POffer, error -> Log.e("Volley_2", error.toString())) 

public void PARSE_R_POffer(JSONArray array) {
        mList_R_POffer.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            R_POffer GetDataAdapter2 = new R_POffer();
            JSONObject json;
            try {
                json = array.getJSONObject(i);
                GetDataAdapter2.set_Package_offer_title(json.getString(GET_PO_TITLE)); 
                prgs_1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                prgs_1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            mList_R_POffer.add(GetDataAdapter2);
        }
        RVA_R_POffer = new Adapter_R_POffer(mList_R_POffer);
        Rec_R_POffer.setAdapter(RVA_R_POffer);
    }
```

Можно сделать что-то подобное с картинкой, то есть вытащить картинку с БД и сослаться на неё в `Adapter`? Если да то как это сделать? Желательно какой-нибудь пример.

Comment: Я получаю url в виде строки и использую библиотеку Glide для встраивания картинки в ImageView в адаптере. Подробнее:  http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/library/glide.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По совету @MarkCain я ознакомился с библиотекой `Glide` которую по итогу и использовал, но также хочу отметить что для выполнения задуманного можно использовать библиотеку `Picasso`.

И так я добавил в свой проект библиотеки

```
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
```

Далее в класс я добавил

```
    public String get_Package_offer_image() {return mPackage_offer_image;}
    public void set_Package_offer_image(String TempImage) {this.mPackage_offer_image = TempImage;}
```

В `Adapter` добавил

```
  private Context context;

  public ImageView img_po;

  img_po = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_po);
    
  Glide.with(context)
                .load(currentItem.get_Package_offer_image())
                .into(holder.img_po);

        holder.getAdapterPosition();
```